# Syncing Javascript Canvas shapes with web video stream

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, synchronization, streaming

Im trying to synchronize a web video stream (rtsp, or whatever) with rectangles that I will draw on canvas. The values of the rectangles will be passed on from a software that will detect some features on the video. The challenge is that there is a lag from the video stream, how can I keep them in sync together so the shape that I will draw will follow the rectangle coordinates being passed?

Comment: I am assuming the lag is because the software takes time give rect co-ords, am I right? how much time does the software take?